# How Do I Pass A Block Through To A Method Call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block, helper, link-to

I need a helper that generates a link wrapped in a `<li>` including an active class.

Without supporting blocks this is easy:

```
  def nav_item(*args, &block)
    url = args[1]
    clazz = 'active' if current_page?(url)

    content_tag(:li, :class => clazz) do
      link_to(*args)
    end
  end
```

But like `link_to` I want my helper to support blocks for defining content. With link_to I can do:

**So how do I support the same in my helper?**

All I need to do is pass the block through to `link_to`. My current attempt

```
  def nav_item(*args, &block)
    url = if block_given?
      args.first
    else
      args[1]
    end
    clazz = 'active' if current_page?(url)
    content_tag(:li, :class => clazz) do
      if block_given?
        # What goes here?
      else
        link_to(*args)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: So your question is how to pass a block to a function when you have the block as a variable, like `block` in your example?

Answer (score 5):

You can just pass the block to `link_to` as the last arg. Like this:

```
def nav_item(*args, &block)
  url = if block_given?
    args.first
  else
    args[1]
  end
  clazz = 'active' if current_page?(url)
  content_tag(:li, :class => clazz) do
    if block
      link_to(*args, &block)
    else
      link_to(*args)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd tried that but it didn't work, turns out this was because of a mistake elsewhere. Thanks.